# Local integrability of the convolution of a function with a distribuition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

Let $G_n$ be the following distribuitions for $n\geq3$  (for $n=2$ it is just a function) in $\mathbb{R^n}$ (the fundamental solutions of the Laplace equation in $\mathbb{R^n}$ ):

$$G_n=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{2 \pi} \cdot \log \left \| x \right \|, \; \; \; n=2
\\ \frac{\left \| x \right \|^{2-n}}{(2-n) \sigma_{n-1}}, \; \; \; n \geq 3
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Where $\sigma_{n-1}$ is the surface area of the unit radius $n$-sphere.

If f $\in L^1(\mathbb{R^n})$ for $n\geq 3$ and $g(y)=f(y) \cdot \log(\left \| y \right \|) \in L^1(\mathbb{R^2})$ for $n=2$ can I get any hint as to how to show that $U=G_n \ast f$ is locally integrable in $\mathbb{R^n}$ for any $n \geq 2$?

Answer (score 3):

At first, you should clarify that $G_n(x) = C_n ||x||^{2-n}$ is the fundamental solution of the Laplace equation. Then $G_n\ast f$ is a continuous function of $x$, so definitely locally integrable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't clarify at first that the $G_n$ are the fundamental solutions of the Laplace equation because i didn't think it would matter.
I don't see, however, why $G_n \ast f$ should be continuous as I can't even be sure that it makes sense, seeing as f is just in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Comment: Or $g(y)=f(y) \cdot \log(\left \| y \right \|) \in L^1(\mathbb{R^2})$ for n=2

Comment: @grizzlyjoker So you mean $G_n$ as you have stated or as I have stated?

Comment: As you have stated, I am thinking about the $G_n$'s as regular distribuitions

Comment: @grizzlyjoker Then please edit the question accordingly. I will edit my answer to explain the case $n=2$ in more details.

Comment: I've done so, thanks for all the help

Comment: @grizzlyjoker Ok, now I see. It is difficult to show it explicitly if $f$ is not bounded.